# Lower bounds on translates of a function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, counterexamples

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and define $f_\theta(x)=f(x-\theta)$. I would like to compute (or at least lower bound) the following:
$$
\inf_{\theta\ne\theta'}\frac{\Vert f_\theta - f_{\theta'}\Vert_p}{|\theta-\theta'|}.
$$
In particular, I want to understand how this depends on $f$, and would like a bound that depends explicitly on $f$. This is also where the properties of $f$ come in: The weaker the assumptions the better, but e.g. if there a nice bound that depends (say) on the deriviatives of $f$, then we can assume the needed regularity.

My suspicion is that there is an easy counterexample to show this can be rather poorly behaved even for smooth functions, but I have not been creative enough so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any real $p\ge1$ and any real $t\ne0$,
$$\frac{\|f_t-f_0\|_p}{|t-0|}
\le\frac{\|f_t\|_p+\|f_0\|_p}{|t|}
=\frac{2\|f\|_p}{|t|}\to0$$
as $|t|\to\infty$.

So, the least lower bound in question is always $0$.

Comment: And what if $\theta$ lay in a compact set, say $\theta\in[a,b]$?

Comment: @tim622 : That would be a very different question (to be posted separately), with a very different answer.

Comment: Sure, done: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398119/lower-bounds-on-translates-of-a-function-over-a-compact-set